# Made specific content type create new file button not visible but still visible to other users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, content-type

I needed to be able to make a specific content type searchable but not allow for new documents with that content type to be created/uploaded to the library.

I did this going in the `Library settings` > `Change new button order` and unchecked the "visible" box next to the content type I wanted to prevent new documents from being made and uploaded.

This has been done but for some reason when another user with access to the site logs in, they can still see the option to create a new file with that content type after clicking the `Create a New File` button.

How do I keep all that have access to the Document Library from seeing that option to create a new document with that content type?

Answer (score 0):

In my SharePoint Online document library, if I unchecked the "visible" in library settings, the content type is not visible for my users.

Please test in other document libraries and check if the issue exists.

And what’s the permission of another user who can view the specific content type you want to hide?

Comment: It looks like they created a new "project"under in the default "project" document library. When this was done, the "new" button displayed document types. Do you know how to edit this?